# Client immediately disconnects

Tags: python, twisted

I'm on Python 2.7 and I'm having a really strange issue with a simple Twisted client.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor
import json, sys, time

class MySpecialClient(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Connection made."

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "Got a line."

class MySpecialClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MySpecialClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection failed:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection lost:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    factory = MySpecialClientFactor()
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 5050, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name___ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem I'm having is that I see "Connection made." in my logs immediately followed by "connection lost: Connection was closed cleanly.". Why is my connection dropping immediately after connection?

Comment: what does the server say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `LineReceiver` with `Protocol` from the same package and changed the `lineReceived` method to `dataReceived` and everything "just worked.™"